# SSL/TLS support in Kaa with ESP8266

Tags: ssl, iot, tls1.2, starttls, kaa

I am new to Kaa and is trying to implement a Kaa based solution with ESP8266. I want to know if it supports SSL/TLS sockets for communication. If not, is there any way to make communication secure (like starttls).

I am currently programming ESP 12E (A variant of ESP8266) using Arduino IDE. Is there any way for me to send data directly to a Kaa installation through secure communication?

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Kaa 0.10, the C SDK uses a hybrid RSA+AES encrypted connection by default.

See [KAA-635](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-635) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Alexey! I am currently programming my ESP12E chip with Arduino IDE. Is there an way through with the Kaa C SDK could be integrated with the arduino code I have already written for my application?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an Arduino user, so can't help you here.